# How to go real full screen mood (f11) in web browsers through code?

Tags: fullscreen

How can I get the browser to switch to full screen mode(f11) through code?

I googled and found various JS results for switching the web browser to full screen mode. The various pieces of code work and I can go full screen and can exit from it, however, when I refresh the page or click on any link on the page while in full screen mode, it switches back to windowed mode.

It seems there are restrictions in the browser of some kind.

The code below works to a degree, but I couldn’t find code that solves this problem. Is it possible to go full screen by code that will remain in full screen even when I click on links?

```
function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
          // ## The below if statement seems to work better ## if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (document.msfullscreenElement && document.msfullscreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
          if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
              if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
                  elem.requestFullScreen();
              } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
              } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                  elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
              } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
              }
          } else {
              if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                  document.cancelFullScreen();
              } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                  document.mozCancelFullScreen();
              } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                  document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
              } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                  document.msExitFullscreen();
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Edited for clarity and language.  I believe that this still accurately reflects what you were trying to ask but in a way that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks David for correction, yes its better and clear than the previous one. hope some one replies any solution.